# kotlin warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: <java_home>!\java.activation

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.3, and I have newest version of kotlin plugin installed, which is currently `kotlin-plugin1.3.11`. Now I just wrote a simple program which prints a string constant. But I keep getting this warning.

```
kotlin warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: <java_home>!\java.activation
```

Why? How to solve it?

Comment: What JDK do you use? There is related report on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25187

Comment: I'm using `Java 9`. I just checked the page you provided. Seems like it's not been answered yet. I do have the exactly same problem as the this page described except that I'm using Java 9 instead of Java 10.